# Exchange of information between the server and client to WCF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, wcf

I have a desktop application built with WPF and a asp.net mvc web application which is located on IIs.

They should exchange information between themselves. Both also have a sql server database.

My question is: What is the best way to create the relationship between the two programs together?

Can WCF a reliable method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF has a class called CallbackContract which can be specified in the ServiceContract attributes. For details you can go to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx